# Applying conditional formatting independently to each other

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

[image]Here is an example file for where I want to apply conditional formatting independently of each other

First I have highlighted all males in the spreadsheet

Then if they are a senior I want the text of the entire row to be bold but I can't seem to get it

The rows where the previous formatting has been applied do not have the second formatting applied

I can understand that if I make another rule where I check both conditions simultaneously I can get the desired result but I ultimately want to have several conditions so this method is not feasible

Any help with this would be appreciated

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cnpsPIZU5Vrz3ung0Dqmv67ECWk8ZaLF0bvtxN6FkGY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional formatting rules are evaluated in the order they are shown in the list. The first rule that evaluates to a truthy value sets the format, and further rules are not evaluated after that.

This means that you need four custom formula rules:

```
=regexmatch($C2, "Senior") * ($B2="Female")

=regexmatch($C2, "Senior") * ($B2="Male")

=$B2 = "Female"

=$B2 = "Male"
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cnpsPIZU5Vrz3ung0Dqmv67ECWk8ZaLF0bvtxN6FkGY/edit#gid=1422683122).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand the solution but the number of rules I need to write double everytime I add a new condition so I was hoping to find a workaround

Comment: That is the way it goes if the criteria overlap — the number of rules grows quadratically. If the criteria do not overlap, the number of rules only grows linearly. One way to handle this with less rules is to format _column by column_, so that the "Senior" column is colored independently of the "Female/male" column.